# Cannot update an object in a Collection - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mern

I am trying to learn React and Redux and am having trouble with what I think should be an easy MongoDB question. I am sure there is an easy solution, but I have been banging my head and do not see it.

below is the sample of my document:

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "store": "Inglewood",
  "stock": [ 
    {
      "product": "apple",
      "count": 4
    },
    {
      "product": "orange",
      "count": 12 
    } 
  ]
}
```

I would like to be able to add new products and also update the existing products.

My code:

```
const updateCount = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
const user = await User.findById(req.user.id)

if(!user) {
    res.status(401)
    throw new Error('User not found')
}

const updatedCount = await DB.findByIdAndUpdate(
      {
        _id: req.body.id,
        count: { {$elemMatch: {product: req.body.product} }
      },
      { $push: {
          stock: {
            product: req.body.product,
            count: req.body.count
          }
        }
      },
      {
        new: true,
        upsert: true,
      }
)

res.status(200).json(updatedCount) })
```

I have tried **$push** and **$addToSet** and those keeps adding new objects to the array. Giving me multiples entries for apples for example.

I have also tried using **$set** and all of the stock items will be erased except the new product.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is check if the product exists before adding or updating it:

```
const updateCount = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const user = await User.findById(req.user.id);
  
    if (!user) {
      res.status(401);
      throw new Error('User not found');
    }
  
    const existingProduct = await DB.findOne({
      _id: req.body.id,
      'stock.product': req.body.product,
    });
  
    let updatedCount;
    if (existingProduct) {
      // Update existing product
      updatedCount = await DB.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: req.body.id, 'stock.product': req.body.product },
        {
          'stock.$.product': {
            count: req.body.count,
          },
        },
        {
          new: true,
          upsert: true,
        }
      );
    } else {
      // Insert new product
      updatedCount = await DB.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.id,
        {
          $push: {
            stock: {
              product: req.body.product,
              count: req.body.count,
            },
          },
        },
        {
          new: true,
          upsert: true,
        }
      );
    }
  
    res.status(200).json(updatedCount);
  });
```